# how to create read only model for cassandra

Tags: python, model, cassandra, readonly

I have cassandra model

```
from cassandra.cqlengine import columns
from cassandra.cqlengine.models import Model

class StudentModules(Model):
    """Model for Student get."""

    __table_name__ = 'students'
    student_id = columns.UUID(primary_key=True, default=uuid4)
    student_name = columns.Text(index=True)
```

In my case, table `students` already exists, and I always want to use this module for `select` query.

I tried `__abstract__` attribute, but in this case, I am not able to call `filter` or `get` call for model.

Comment: did you figure out how to do this?

Comment: @RohanMonga not yet :(

Comment: @RohanMonga do you have any idea to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a built-in way to do this. You could get behavior like that by defining an intermediate class and overriding the mutation methods*:

```
class ROModel(Model):
    __abstract__=True

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, **_):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def save(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def update(self, **_):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def delete(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

class Test(ROModel):
    __keyspace__='test'
    k = columns.Integer(primary_key=True)
    a = columns.Integer()
    b = columns.Integer()

print Test.objects.first()
Test(k=1, b=4).update()  # NotImplementedError
Test.create(k=1, a=2, b=3)  # NotImplementedError
Test(k=1).delete()  # NotImplementedError
Test(k=1, a=3).save()  # NotImplementedError
```

* note that this is only a partial solution -- you would also need to update `ROModel.__queryset__` with a similarly specialized `query.ModelQuerySet`.

However, I'm having trouble understanding what this buys you. Any solution making the thing read-only will result in a runtime error if you call a mutating method.

In any case, you might also be better off using auth and a user/role with only select permissions.
https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/security.html#data-control